# most efficient way to repeatedly search a Scala iterator

Tags: scala, iterator, find

I have a large text file that consists of Word2Vec vectors built from Gigaword (it's over 3GB in size), each line is a word and its corresponding vector.  It's ordered by frequency so that a word with high frequency is higher in the list than a low frequency word.

For a given list of words, I need to build a Scala Map that consists of the word and it's word2vec vector.  Below is my approach:

---

1. for each word, open the file as an iterator:

   `val it = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath).getLines()`
2. use `find` to find matching word, with a default value if not found:

   `val match = it.find(_.split(" ").head == word).getOrElse("zzz" 0d)`

---

Here is my full method:

```
def buildArray2b: (Double, Array[(String, breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double])]) = {
val startAll = System.currentTimeMillis().toDouble
val stream = (for (word <- this.vocabulary.map(each => each.toLowerCase)) yield {
  println("starting " + word)
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis().toDouble
  println("building iterator")
  val iterator = Source.fromInputStream(this.inputStream).getLines()
  println("finding")
  val line = iterator.find(it => it.split(" ").head == word).getOrElse("zzz 0.0")
  println("found")
  val splitLine = line.split(" ")                                                                       //split string into elements
  val tail = splitLine.tail.map(_.toDouble)                                                             //build w2v vector
  val vectorizedLine = splitLine.head -> breeze.linalg.DenseVector(tail)                                //build map entry
  val stop = System.currentTimeMillis().toDouble
  println(word + ":" + (stop - start) / 1000d)
  vectorizedLine
}).toArray
val stopAll = System.currentTimeMillis().toDouble
val elapsed = (stopAll - startAll) / 1000d
(elapsed, stream)
```

}

And here is the output with times to find the following words "a" "quixotic" and "the":

```
scala> w2v.buildArray2
a:0.001
quixotic:0.795
the:25.6
```

I have no idea why it's taking no time to find "quixotic" (which should be "far down" in the list compared to "a" and "the"), but forever to find the word "the".

I have very little experience with data structures, and so I'm grateful for (1) any insight into this issue and (2) any suggestions on how to make this process more efficient.

To that effect, I have already tried the following:

1. Load the entire file into a Map.  This takes a very long time to first convert to a sequence and then a map.
2. Convert the .txt file into .json and then use a package (in this case `json4s`) to open that .json file directly into a map.  I'm running into memory errors (and I already have 14g of memory allocated to this project).

Thanks in advance for any comments/insight!

Answer (score 2):

## Using a Map

As long as you have no memory problem using a `Map[String,Vector[String]]` would be a good option to start with.
Read the file once and put the data into a Map. Your are almost there already because almost all `Seq[Tuple2]`can be easily transformed to a map using `toMap`.
And you will get `constant time access` for each key.

## Conversion to json

This would add an additional step of indirection. It would only let the data that needs to be parsed and processed grow and make the process even slower.

## Iterator and reuse

Citing the official Scala Documentation : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator `They have a hasNext method for checking if there is a next element available, and a next method which returns the next element and discards it from the iterator.` So by definition an `Iterator` is not reusable.

Answer (score 1):

Scala's `Iterator` is stateful and not intended to be shared or reused. Any sharing or reuse that may be possible depends entirely on the underlying resource being iterated over. I.e. you can iterate over a file multiple times safely, but reusing an iterator on a download stream doesn't make sense.

You can do this in linear time & constant space by turning `vocabulary` into `Map` or `Set`. At a high level, you need to iterate each line in the word2vec file and check whether that word is in your `vocabulary`, then if it is add that word & weight to the map like this:

```
val vocab = this.vocabulary.toSet
val it = Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).getLines
val result: Map[String, DenseVector] = foldLeft(Map.empty[String, DenseVector]){(acc, line) => 
    val Array(word, weight) = line.split(" ")
    if(vocab.contains(word))
         acc + (word -> breeze.linalg.DenseVector(weight.toDouble))
    else 
         acc
 }
```

`foldLeft` iterates from the left side (i.e. head) of the iterator through the entire file. At each line, it checks whether the word is a vocab word, then if so adds it to a map (`acc`), which is then returned once all of the iterator has been processed.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas Neumann and Chris.  I may not have made my question clear.  I do *NOT* want to iterate through the entire word2vec file if I don't have to.  It is *HUGE* and on average my `vocabulary` is only about 500 distinct words.  That's why I using `find` which would never have to go through the entire word2vec file *IF* all the words in my vocabulary exist.

Comment: You can optimize for that and remove elements from the vocabulary set as they're found, then terminate the loop once all vocab words have been found.